# Sharepoint 2010 slow

Tags: networking, domain-name-system, sql, sharepoint-2010

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Slow Sharepoint Server 2010](https://serverfault.com/questions/164131/slow-sharepoint-server-2010)

I have a sharepoint 2010 installation that is running really slowly.

The installation is set up as follows,

- I have a domain controller (Server 2008 64 bit) with active directory and DNS set up
- I have an application server that is running SQL 2008 and sharepoint
- There is one site set up on the sharepoint server
- SQL has one server farm created
- All installations are administered by active directory accounts, no local accounts are used.

Loading any pages (including the administration panel) is very slow, I originally thought that it might have been the calls to DHCP and DNS on my router that couldnt be resolved and then being sent back to my DC to let the DNS resolve it there.
I came to this conclusion as the pages do somtimes load but the takes well over 3 minutes to load a page and then somtimes generates an error. When I check the CPU usage, its totaly maxed out to 100%

So I created my own personal intranet that only used a hub to connect the network to test my theory, however, since creating the intranet, the pages are just as slow. I have turned off the cache on my browser as well and cleaned any internet history.

After this, I re-installed everything (as im using eSXI to host the virtual boxes) and made sure that everything was stripped back to the bare minimum to save on CPU usage but nothing seems to be working.

I just need to find a way of lowering the CPU usage and make the pages load faster. any help would be appricated.

Comment: is this entirely virtualized on the same host?

Comment: The first time you load a site it can take a long time although 3 minutes seems a lot. After that first hit things should speed up though.  It seems an obvisous question but is the hardware good enough to run the two VMs as SP expects a decent amount of resources.  Can you detail the set-up in more detail... e.g. hardware, virtualisation product used, resources allocated to each VM etc?

Comment: they are on the same physical box, but diffrent hard drives.

Comment: @chris W - Its all brand new hardware. Intel Core i5 CPU 750 @ 2.67, 4055.56mb RAM, 2 x 250 HHD's, running ESXi 4 to virtualise the machiene.

Everything is linked up and the site does load (eventually) but everything is just really slow. Is there any crawl settings that I could lower down to make it all a bit quicker?

Answer (score 0):

Did you have a look at [A new approach to solve SharePoint’s painfully slow spin-up / start-up time for first request](http://blog.muhimbi.com/2009/04/new-approach-to-solve-sharepoints.html)?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen DNS slow things down before - which you should be able to test with `ping`

```
ping SQL-Server
```

If it does not start returning packets immediately, or the latency is over 10ms, then you have networking issues. In my case the initial lookup of the host name was taking about 5-10 seconds, then traffic would flow normally. Simply adding the impact host name to the local hosts file (c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts) with the correct IP address solved the issue.