# Slow Sharepoint Server 2010

Tags: domain-name-system, performance, sharepoint, performance-monitoring

I have a sharepoint 2010 installation that is running really slowly.

The installation is set up as follows,

- I have a domain controller (Server 2008 64 bit) with active directory and DNS set up
- I have an application server that is running SQL 2008 and sharepoint
- There is one site set up on the sharepoint server
- SQL has one server farm created
- All installations are administered by active directory accounts, no local accounts are used.

Loading any pages (including the administration panel) is very slow, I originally thought that it might have been the calls to DHCP and DNS on my router that couldnt be resolved and then being sent back to my DC to let the DNS resolve it there.
I came to this conclusion as the pages do somtimes load but the takes well over 3 minutes to load a page and then somtimes generates an error. When I check the CPU usage, its totaly maxed out to 100%

So I created my own personal intranet that only used a hub to connect the network to test my theory, however, since creating the intranet, the pages are just as slow. I have turned off the cache on my browser as well and cleaned any internet history.

After this, I re-installed everything (as im using eSXI to host the virtual boxes) and made sure that everything was stripped back to the bare minimum to save on CPU usage but nothing seems to be working.

I just need to find a way of lowering the CPU usage and make the pages load faster. any help would be appricated.